# nodejs http request compression (without express but with the possibility of renderize files with jade)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, gzip, zlib

How to send compressed gzipped file when requested from client ?

For example I have:

```
var zlib = require("zlib"),
    http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    /*req.url is the url of the file requested
    how to compress and send the file here?
    consider that usually (facoltative) I can renderize the file also with Jade.renderFile()
    so the best solution is to compress the output before sending to client */
}).listen(80);
```

and how to cache for avoid multiple gzip requests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved compressing html data returned by jade.renderFile() callback